# IF statement not fired

Tags: if-statement, batch-file, dos

I have small calcutations in dos .bat file:

```
FOR /F "tokens=1-3 delims=/-" %%A IN ("%tag%") DO (
   SET Day=%%C
   SET Month=%%B
   SET /a Year=%%A - 2000
)

echo %Day%
echo %Month%
echo %Year%

echo %stamp%


IF %Month% == "02" (

  echo "Iam in"
)
```

Today if Feb so Month is comming as 02 but if condition has not being meet. What I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your quotes are part of the string that is compared. You need to include them on both sides:

```
if "%Month%" == "02" (
  echo "Iam in"
)
```

or not have them on either side:

```
if %Month% == 02 (
  echo "Iam in"
)
```

Comment: thank you for it, I also find out that define as Month integer `SET /a Month=%%C` allow to use `IF %Month% == 2 (...` `